# Google Autocomplete service for places (cities, countries, not establishment such as business)

Tags: android

I need to offer in my application the ability to predict (auto suggest) places, as user typing. I know that Google have such service. The issue is, Google Autocomplete service predict places (business) while I need to autocomplete, places, such as cities, countries (not establishment such as business). Does Google or others offer this service?

thanks,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Javascript:

[Link to Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html)

Yes, set the types to geocode and it will only give suggestions to places, and not businesses.

```
var acOptions = {
  bounds: ACdefaultBounds,
  types: ['geocode']
};

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, acOptions);
```